# SQL Server Configuration File and InstanceName parameter

Tags: sql-server, installation, automation

We have a configuration file at `E:\SQL_Server_2016_Install\MyConfigFile.ini` that looks like below:

```
[OPTIONS]
ACTION = "Install"
FEATURES = SQLENGINE
INSTANCENAME = MSSQLSERVER
AGTSVCACCOUNT = "MyDomain\MyAccount"
SQLSVCACCOUNT = "MyDomain\MyAccount"
QS
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

SQL Server is then installed using below batch file:
`E:\SQL_Server_2016_Install\Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=MyConfigFile.ini /InstanceName="TestSQLServer"`

Question:

Will `/InstanceName="TestSQLServer"` parameter override what we have in the configuration file (`/InstanceName = MSSQLSERVER` (default instance)), and install SQL Server as a named instance `TestSQLServer` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will /InstanceName="TestSQLServer" parameter override what we have in
> the configuration file (/InstanceName = MSSQLSERVER (default
> instance)), and install SQL Server as a named instance "TestSQLServer"
> ?

Yes, per the below excerpt from the [configuration file documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file) :

- The configuration file overwrites the defaults in a package
- Command-line values overwrite the values in the configuration file